# How to add WebMatrix _Admin page to asp.net mvc site? Getting access to Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, webmatrix

I can create a WebMatrix 3 site and access the Admin Console via http://localhost:[PORT]/_Admin.

**[ISSUE]**
I can't seem to be able to access _Admin page via a newly created asp.net mvc site, that is hosted in WebMatrix. I wanted to get access to the Web Helpers.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Pav

Comment: The URL for webmatrix web helpers is http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205388

Comment: MVC does not work inside of the WebMatrix tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reference System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll on C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET...Web Pages

ApplicationPart.Register that assembly on virtual path "~/_admin".

in example RegisterRoutes in global.asax,

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        ApplicationPart part = new ApplicationPart(
            typeof(System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin).Assembly,
            "~/_admin");
        ApplicationPart.Register(part);
        // initialize your route table bellow
```

Comment: (Y) thanks for finding i am not sure why WebMatrix is not directly supporting it even when Scott Hanselman demonstrated that in mix2011